# How can I get two different countdowns on the same page?

Tags: javascript

I am using the [jQuery Countdown](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_countdown) module, and I want to add two (or more) countdowns to my webpage.

I am using the following code for the first countdown.

```
echo '<div class="countdown">10 seconds!</div>';
jquery_countdown_add(".countdown", array("until" => $a, "onExpiry" => "finished"));
drupal_add_js("function finished() { alert('You are done!'); }", 'inline');
```

If I use that code for 2 or more countdowns, they show the same countdown, not different countdowns.

Comment: Did you try using different selectors, for example using a CSS ID for the first, and another one for the other counter?

Comment: different css selector for what?for which div or element?I tried all of them.I know where is the problem.The problem is in ".countdown". this is the name of an array that it created and used everywhere.I tried to make different name for array but when I change the name of array the countdown doesn't working

Comment: I found the answer!You were right!2 thing is important:1.class.2.array=>the name of class and the array should be the same!one of the count down can be countdown_1 and othere can be count down_2